# Bash Storing Text File as Variable and Outputting Multiple Variables on Same Line

Tags: bash

I'm having trouble with this for loop. It's behaving as expected if I echo each variable on a separate line, but for whatever reason, I can't echo them on the same line. This is a snippet of the code, which is ultimately fed into a INSERT statement for MySQL.

```
for work in $(find "$INCOMINGDIR" -type f -name *.txt)
do
   #First, extract metadata from zip and load as variable:
   INFO=$(unzip -c "${work%*.txt}".zip master.nfo)

   #Next, parse out the desired text:
   REP=$(echo "$INFO" | grep "Rep Name" | awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
   LNAME=$(echo "$INFO" | grep "Last Name" | awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
   FNAME=$(echo "$INFO" | grep "First Name" | awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
   PKGNAME=$(echo "${work%*.txt}".zip | sed 's/.*\///')

echo "$PKGNAME" "$LNAME" "$FNAME" "$REP"
done
```

Currently, this is the output:

```
 jmartin2917_49b79545-3816-475e-9a57-c238f0f3cb47.zip DOE
```

^this space is there. Also, jmartin = $REP, $PKGNAME is cutoff, $FNAME is missing.

Echo'ing on separate lines, in the same order results in:

```
CDC1000_042917_49b79545-3816-475e-9j57-c238f0f3cb47.zip
DOE
JANE
jmartin
```

So, expected result is:

```
CDC1000_042917_49b79545-3816-475e-9j57-c238f0f3cb47.zipDOEJANEjmartin
```

Any suggestion on how to identify if the input file is causing the problem? I redirected the unzip to a text file and opened it with nano and didn't see unusual characters or unusual formatting. The very odd thing is that if I do something like, say, drop the $REP, the formatting gets garbled in a different way:

```
 JANE0_042917_49b79545-3816-475e-9a57-c238f0f3cb47.zip DOE
```

Somehow these are stepping over each other. Very confused.

Comment: seems you already tried `echo "$var1 $var ..."`. could you post a snippet of what you get then..

Comment: What is the output that you are getting with this? & what is the expected output? Is it possible, that these variables have embedded newline characters?

Comment: Updated the post with more detail.

Comment: Have you tried `echo "$PKGNAME$LNAME$FNAME$REP"`?

Comment: Your foundation for the whole for loop and the `work` variable is the results of the `find` command - but you are not handling the possibility of spaces in these files, can you show us the contents of `"$INCOMINGDIR"`?

Comment: You generally see the loop written as `while read -r line; do ...stuff...; done < <(find "$INCOMINGDIR" -type f -name *.txt)` to take advantage of *process substitution*. **note:** the `space` between `< <`. You can also do `for work in "$INCOMINGDIR"/*; do ..stuff..; done`

Comment: echo "$PKGNAME$LNAME$FNAME$REP" results in the same behavior. It's like $PKGNAME is anchored in some weird way.

Comment: Okay, so I isolated the issue to the $INFO and $PKGNAME variables. If I replace $INFO with a simple, static command like INFO=$(cat "$INCOMINGDIR/master.nfo"), then all is fine. Replacing the for loop with a while doesn't resolve the issue though. So, the interaction with the find command and parsing that variable $work is causing an issue. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out...the joys of working with files created in Windows. Using the file command to output info about it provides:

```
incoming$ file master.nfo 
master.nfo: ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

anishsane was on the right track. Modifying the script to write to a temp file then running dos2unix to convert from CRLF to LF (unix line termination) with the following:

```
unzip -c "${work%*.txt}".zip master.nfo > "$INCOMINGDIR"/"${work%*.txt}"_master.nfo && dos2unix "$INCOMINGDIR"/"${work%*.txt}"_master.nfo
INFO=$(cat "$INCOMINGDIR"/"${work%*.txt}"_master.nfo)
```

Multiple variables on the same line are now working. Just another reminder when working with text files to test line termination in case it came from Windows.

Comment: You can simplify the conversion to `INFO=$(unzip -c "${work%*.txt}".zip master.nfo | tr -d '\r')`

Comment: Thanks, that might be better than having to resort to another utility. I also found that dos2unix can do stdin to stdout, so I could also do:    `INFO=$(unzip -c "${work%*.FINISHED.txt}".zip master.nfo | dos2unix )`. But, I prefer your suggestion of using `tr` since it'll be more portable. Thanks!